# php - Accessing variables within a function defined in another function?

Tags: php, function, variables, tags, defined

I'm trying to get variables that I defined while in a function from another function I called in that function, example:

```
$thevar = 'undefined';
Blablahblah();
echo $thevar; (should echo blaaah)
function Blahedit(){

     echo $thevar; (should echo blah)
     $thevar = 'blaaah';

}
function Blablahblah(){

     global $thevar;
     $thevar = 'blah';
     Blahedit();

}
```

I want to know if there's another way of doing this without passing down params to Blahedit(), get_defined_vars gives me vars within the function not $thevar... and calling global $thevar will just give me the previous unedited version.

Please help ):

Comment: You already did this in the latter function, just add `global $thevar;` to the former function as well.

Comment: *Why?!* Why would you want such a thing? It burns my eyes just looking at it!

Comment: Global variables are a very bad idea. Why not use parameters? Simpler and safer

Comment: global $thevar; gives me $thevar = 'undefined'...

Comment: I just want to know if there's another way of going about, and yes it is simpler thank you Ed and Madara for being the only two actually reading what I said ♥

Comment: The other thing I can do is use a class obj (which is in my actual code) define variables there, assign them to the var and pass that back, but that is a mess and would be stupid considering the fact that im just using those variables for 1 function.

Comment: @user1936522 - Why is that stupid? OOD would not go a miss here as it will make your code scalable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

or better have a look at oop

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variables [as a reference parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) (shown below), encapsulate your code in a class and use your variable as class attribute or let the functions return the changed variable.

```
$thevar = 'undefined';
Blablahblah($thevar);
echo $thevar; 

function Blahedit(&$thevar){
     echo $thevar;
     $thevar = 'blaaah';
}

function Blablahblah(&$thevar){
     $thevar = 'blah';
     Blahedit($thevar);
}
```

**Using globals inside functions is considered to be a bad practice**. However, passing a lot of variables by reference also is not good style.

If you want to get your code to work the way it is, you have to add a `global $thevar` to your edit function:

```
function Blahedit(){
     global $thevar;
     echo $thevar; (should echo blah)
     $thevar = 'blaaah';
}
```

Comment: I already know this is possible through params, I want to know if there's another way without doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Just global $thevar inside blahedit.

```
function Blahedit(){
    global $thevar;
    echo $thevar; //(should echo blah)
    $thevar = 'blaaah';

}
```

Comment: Global calls upon the old $thevar (undefined) and I want the edited version passed by blablahblah